# Using (Schoenfield) Absoluteness Theorem to deduce algorithm termination

Tags: logic, algorithms, propositional-calculus, axiom-of-choice

I've been taking a lecture course on Logic and Verification which has been focussing on automation of logical proofs of tautologies and similar such things. Recently, we discussed an algorithm for converting any formula in propositional logic into Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF). The algorithm is rather simple to describe.

If we are given a propositional formula $X$, write it as $\langle[X]\rangle$ where $\langle X_1,X_2,..., X_n\rangle$ represents the conjunction of the formulae $X_1,..., X_n$ and where $[X_1,..., X_n]$ is the disjunction of these formulae. Then given a current stage of the expansion $\langle D_1,..., D_n\rangle$ select one of the disjunctions $D_i$ that is not a disjunction of literals and select a non-literal $N$ from $D_i$ and:

- If $N = \neg \top, \neg \bot$ replace it by $\bot, \top$ respectively.
- If $N = \neg\neg Z$ then replace it by $Z$.
- If it is a beta-formula (i.e. a disjunction of two formulae $B_1,B_2$) then replace it by the two formula squence $B_1, B_2$ in the disjunction (e.g. $[X\vee Y, Z, W]$ would become $[X,Y,Z,W]$).
- If it is an alpha-formula (i.e. it contains a conjunction $\alpha_1\wedge \alpha_2$), then replace $N$ with a sequence of two disjunctions where one has the conjunction replaced with $\alpha_1$ and another where it is replaced with $\alpha_2$ (e.g. $[X\wedge Y, Z]$ would become $[X,Z],[Y,Z]$).

If no such disjunction exists, terminate.

Anyway, the point is that the lecturer wanted to know that this algorithm always terminated (as correctness is very easy to establish) and ended up using [Kőnig's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma). However, as you can see on that page this lemma's proof requires a weak form of choice and it seems utterly bizarre to me that this algorithm's termination would depend on Choice.

I thus suspect there's a proof of termination without using Choice and in particular wondered if we might be able to do a slick proof using some powerful results from Logic. **Can we use an absoluteness theorem somehow, such as the famous one due to Schoenfield, to show that we can remove choice from the proof of termination of the algorithm?**

I suspect that the analytical complexity of the statement that this algorithm terminates is fairly low but I don't quite know enough about logic and these kinds of results to say much about this with complete certainty.

Comment: If your logic has only countably many propositonal variables, then using Kőnig's lemma requires no choice. If you have more, then in what sense does Shoenfield is applicable, if you can't code the thing into a real?

Comment: Shoenfield absoluteness is overkill here. The particular applications of König's Lemma used in this proof don't need choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ah so the countable case doesn't require choice! That's perfect. Out of interest, could you elaborate on this concept of encoding something into a real? I'm not aware of this idea about how to apply Shoenfield... (as I said, fairly out of my depth in this area of logic)

Comment: The absoluteness theorem is about projective statements of low complexity, namely a statement about real numbers with a certain complexity. To appeal to it, you need to make whatever you're using into real numbers, or, in other words, encode your data as reals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Reading your comment made go back and read some texts and I realised I thought the Absoluteness Theorem was actually certain consequences of it! Anyway, the message is noted: I could theoretically use the theorem in this case with countably many variables but it's not at all necessary as we have a simple proof explicitly of Konig without Choice.